# A club in an $\omega_1$ tree

Tags: set-theory

Given an $\omega_1$ tree $T$ one needs to prove $\{\alpha\in Lim:\ T{\restriction_\alpha} = \alpha \}$ is a club in $\omega_1$.

Why would such a set even be non-empty? What if $T$ is composed of two separate branches of length $\omega_1$? Then $T{\restriction_\alpha}$ is just two separate branches of length $\alpha$... It can't be of order type $\alpha$, because there are elements that cannot be compared.

I certainly misunderstood the problem, but I'm not able to even begin to think of a solution if I disagree with the statement.

Could you, please, help me?

Comment: To see why your 'counterexample' isn't one: You may very well have to distinct branches of height $\omega_{1}$ and you're right that any elements that don't belong to the same branch are incompatible *with respect to the tree order $\le_{T}$*. However, as Brian's answer shows, since $T = \omega_{1}$ there are club many levels, all of whose elements are compatible with respect to the $\le$-order of ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re missing, I think, is that as a set the tree $T$ is simply $\omega_1$: its elements are the countable ordinals.

Fix $\alpha_0<\omega_1$. Given $\alpha_n<\omega_1$ for some $n\in\omega$, there is an $\alpha_{n+1}$ such that $\alpha_n<\alpha_{n+1}<\omega_1$, $\alpha_n\subseteq T\upharpoonright\alpha_{n+1}$, and $T\upharpoonright \alpha_n\subseteq\alpha_{n+1}$. Let $\alpha=\sup_n\alpha_n$; then $T\upharpoonright\alpha=\alpha$. This already shows that the set in question is unbounded, and closure is easy.

Comment: $T\upharpoonright \alpha_n\subseteq\alpha_{n+1}$ holds since $T\upharpoonright \alpha_n$ is a countable union of countable ordinals, so there exists a larger countable cardinal, is that right? And $\alpha_n\subseteq T\upharpoonright\alpha_{n+1}$ because $T\upharpoonright\alpha_{n+1}$ has at least $\alpha_{n+1}$ elements?

Comment: @Jules: $T\upharpoonright\alpha_n$ is simply a countable subset of $\omega_1$, so it’s certainly bounded in $\omega_1$. Similarly, each $\xi\in\alpha_n$ must appear in some level $\beta(\xi)$, and the set of $\beta(\xi)$ for $\xi\in\alpha_n$ is countable and hence bounded in $\omega_1$. We just need to choose $\alpha_{n+1}$ to be an upper bound for both sets.

Comment: Alright, I understand now, thank you!

Comment: @Jules: You’re welcome!